# Pydantic: how to make model with some mandatory and arbitrary number of other optional fields, which names are unknown and can be any?

Tags: pydantic

I'd like to represent the following json by Pydantic model:

```
{
   "sip" {
     "param1": 1
   }
   "param2": 2
   ...
}
```

Means json may contain `sip` field and some other field, any number any names, so I'd like to have model which have `sip:Optional[dict]` field and some kind of "rest", which will be correctly parsed from/serialized to json. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [`extra` model config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options):

> `extra`
>
> whether to ignore, allow, or forbid extra attributes during model initialization. Accepts the string values of `'ignore'`, `'allow'`, or `'forbid'`, or values of the `Extra` enum (default: `Extra.ignore`). `'forbid'` will cause validation to fail if extra attributes are included, `'ignore'` will silently ignore any extra attributes, and `'allow'` will assign the attributes to the model.

Example:

```python
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional

import pydantic


class Foo(pydantic.BaseModel):
    sip: Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]

    class Config:
        extra = pydantic.Extra.allow


foo = Foo.parse_raw(
    """
{
   "sip": {
     "param1": 1
   },
   "param2": 2
}
"""
)

print(repr(foo))
print(foo.json())
```

Output:

```
Foo(sip={'param1': 1}, param2=2)
{"sip": {"param1": 1}, "param2": 2}
```